# The WhatsApp macOS app created a "WhatsApp" folder on my desktop

Tags: macos, whatsapp.app

I installed WhatsApp's new native macOS desktop app today, and it created a folder on my desktop called `WhatsApp` with two files `desktop.WhatsApp.bom.log` and `net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.bom.log`
in it.

What is this folder? What are these files? Can I just delete it? Can I move it somewhere? I don't want this folder on the desktop.

Comment: I would say those files are for storing WhatsApp logs (from their names). Maybe just try moving it somewhere and see what happens, you can just undo if it causes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

### You can delete those files

Those files are part of the post-installation process that lists the customizations and/or 3rd party plugins that were active at the time the software was installed.

Are your contacts safe?

**Yes**

All contacts are stored in a SQLite database. The fact the showed up on your Desktop might warrant a bug report. Preferences are likely stored in a binary plist format. Therefore you‘ll need a tool like `plistbuddy`. Just keep that in mind.

#### Can I remove?

So, is it safe  to remove? The biggest issue will be if you contact support and the ask for the file, you won’t have it to give to a (tech) support person starting from scratch. Other than that, you’re free to move, delete, open, etc. with no risk.